# Compiling ideviceinstaller on Mac

Tags: xcode, macos, makefile

I'm trying to compile ideviceinstaller on a mac(OS X 10.10.4) with Xcode 6.2

Got all prerequisites compiled, however when I make i get

```
make
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  all-recursive
Making all in src
  CC       ideviceinstaller-ideviceinstaller.o
  CCLD     ideviceinstaller
original-clang: error: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
make[2]: *** [ideviceinstaller] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Even using

```
ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future
```

or

```
sudo ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future
```

produces the same result.

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong ?